# Error reason from Perl Net::FTP

Tags: perl, error-handling, ftp, mainframe

I'm using Net::FTP to transfer files up to a mainframe and I'm testing failure conditions.

My code is basically along the following lines:

```
    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new ("mainframe.com", Timeout => 20);
    if (! $ftp) {
            logMessage ("Could not connect to host: $!");
            return;
    }

    if (! $ftp->login ("paxdiablo", "demigodemporeroftheuniverse")) {
            logMessage ("Could not log in to host: $!");
            $ftp->quit ();
            return;
    }

    if (! $ftp->put ("myfile.txt", "'CANT.WRITE.TO.THIS'")) {
            logMessage ("Could not put file: $!");
            $ftp->quit ();
            return;
    }
```

I *know* I can't create the data set `CANT.WRITE.TO.THIS` since I don't have the required permissions but, when I try, the only message I see is:

```
Could not put file:
```

There is no indication in `$!` as to what the problem was. I've looked in the [`Net::FTP` doco](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/FTP.html) and all it says is:

> **`put ( LOCAL_FILE [, REMOTE_FILE ] )`**
> `Put a file on the remote server. LOCAL_FILE may be a name or a filehandle. If LOCAL_FILE is a filehandle then REMOTE_FILE must be specified. If REMOTE_FILE is not specified then the file will be stored in the current directory with the same leafname as LOCAL_FILE.`
> `Returns REMOTE_FILE or the generated remote filename if REMOTE_FILE is not given.`

I also cannot find anything there about retrieving the specific error (like `$ftp->getLastError()` or something similar).

How can I indicate to the user *why* the transfer failed?

On an earlier iteration, I resorted to putting the file, then getting it again and checking contents locally. I'd really rather *not* have to inflict such kludgy code on people again.

Comment: You could submit a small job via the FTP server to try and create dataset CANT.WRITE.TO.THIS.  Then parse the JESLOG for RACF or ACF2 messages indicating a more specific error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Net::FTP](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFTP):

> ```
> $ftp = Net::FTP->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0)
>     or die "Cannot connect to some.host.name: $@"
> ```

Note **`$@`**.

> ```
> $ftp->cwd("/pub")
>     or die "Cannot change working directory ", $ftp->message;
> ```

Note **`$ftp->message`**

Comment: Aarrgghh!! Silly doco. No mention of message() in the actual description section, just in the sample code. I see from Net::Cmd, it comes from there but it really should state _what_ it inherits - I notice it doesn't seem to give youe code() for example. Still, that's not your fault, and you helped a great deal so +1 and accept.